# Parking utilization - R

Tags: r, date

I have entry and exit times of parking spots. How to find out the utilization of parking spots at a given time?

Here is a sample of my data: the sID is parking space number, entry and exit times of actual cars. pID is the user ID

```
p_id    sID        entrytime                exittime
40114   25     2013-11-18 15:49:27     2013-11-19 05:00:00
39173   58     2013-11-18 14:34:22     2013-11-19 05:00:00
12549   07     2013-11-18 13:55:13     2013-11-19 05:00:00
39475   48     2013-11-18 13:31:14     2013-11-19 05:00:00
12549   70     2013-11-18 10:35:56     2013-11-19 05:00:00
39173   99     2013-11-18 10:15:52     2013-11-19 05:00:00
12549   99     2013-11-18 10:02:06     2013-11-19 05:00:00
39909   76     2013-11-18 08:04:38     2013-11-19 05:00:00
39038   01     2013-11-15 15:47:13     2013-11-16 04:00:00
39807   91     2013-11-15 14:30:19     2013-11-16 02:30:19
40629   31     2013-11-19 08:13:42     2013-11-19 20:13:42
```

Ideally, this will be my output, which will consist of hourly (or 30-min) utilization of the parking lot accross the different parking dates. 'No.parksUtilized' is the number of parking spots in use at that specific time. Below table is not real data, just for illustration purpose

```
        time           No.parksUtilized
2013-11-15 08:00:00         13
2013-11-15 09:00:00          5
2013-11-15 10:00:00          9
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce how you get your output?!

Comment: I have added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your output might be based on more data than you've shown in your data sample. Below is an example of how to proceed.

First, set up your sample data in a usable form:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat = read.table(text="
40114 25 2013-11-18 15:49:27 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 39173 58 2013-11-18 14:34:22 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 12549 07 2013-11-18 13:55:13 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 39475 48 2013-11-18 13:31:14 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 12549 70 2013-11-18 10:35:56 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 39173 99 2013-11-18 10:15:52 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 12549 99 2013-11-18 10:02:06 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 39909 76 2013-11-18 08:04:38 2013-11-19 05:00:00
                 39038 01 2013-11-15 15:47:13 2013-11-16 04:00:00
                 39807 91 2013-11-15 14:30:19 2013-11-16 02:30:19
                 40629 31 2013-11-19 08:13:42 2013-11-19 20:13:42", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


names(dat) = c("p_id", "sID",  "entrytime", "v1", "exittime", "v2")

dat = dat %>% 
  mutate(entrytime = ymd_hms(paste(entrytime, v1)),
         exittime = ymd_hms(paste(exittime, v2))) %>% 
  select(-v1, -v2)
```

Count occupied spaces:

```
times = seq(ymd_hms("2013-11-18 08:00:00"), ymd_hms("2013-11-18 18:00:00"), by="1 hour")

map_df(times, function(x) {
  data.frame(timecheck=x, 
             Num_Occupied=sum(with(dat, between(x, entrytime, exittime))))
})
```

> ```
>              timecheck Num_Occupied
> 1  2013-11-18 08:00:00            0
> 2  2013-11-18 09:00:00            1
> 3  2013-11-18 10:00:00            1
> 4  2013-11-18 11:00:00            4
> 5  2013-11-18 12:00:00            4
> 6  2013-11-18 13:00:00            4
> 7  2013-11-18 14:00:00            6
> 8  2013-11-18 15:00:00            7
> 9  2013-11-18 16:00:00            8
> 10 2013-11-18 17:00:00            8
> 11 2013-11-18 18:00:00            8
> ```

Comment: Thanks! seems like it's the right approach but map_df is throwing an error

Comment: Please paste into your question the code you ran, the specific error message, and the data sample you used. Provide the data sample by pasting in your question the output of `dput(data_sample)`. For example, if you want to provide the first 20 rows of your data do `dput(dat[1:20, ])`.

Comment: Thanks, I used the exact same code and data from your answer.  Below is the error:  Error in between(x, entrytime, exittime) : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=11].

Answer (score 0):

I think you just showed us a part of your data and I do not completely understand your final table, but you can handle this as hint for your problem. I would solve it with the package `lubridate`.

```
package(lubridate)

df$entrytime <- ymd_hms(df$entrytime)
df$exittime <- ymd_hms(df$exittime)

interval <- interval(start = df$entrytime, end = df$exittime)

date <- ymd_hms("2013-11-15 15:00:00")

length(date %within% interval)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had come to almost the same point, my issue is finding the occupancy keeping in mind entry and exit times. Running this code, I'm getting the length of my dataset as an answer, I'm probably missing something here..